# ConTeXt: how to set different interlinelinespace for \framed text?

Tags: context, framed

I'm working with a document that has many framed objects (to be more specific, they live on a different layer - that is, they are specified with `\setlayerframed` macro). I use the combination of `\setupframed` and `\setuplayer` to set up common parameters for all of them. With the exception of `interlinespacing`.  For the time being, I use `\setuplocalinterlinespace` (with the same parameter) within each frame. Is there a better way - that is, either to create a derivative of `\setlayerframed` or to have some global setting for interlinespacing within the framed context?

Comment: `\setupframed[extras={\setuplocalinterlinespace[<whatever>]}]`?

Comment: You can use the `style` key to set the interlinespace, e.g. `\framed[style={\setupinterlinespace[...]}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `\framed` as well in other environments you can use the `style` — or `foregroundstyle` for `\framed` commands — key to set a different interline space.

```
\defineframed
  [ParagraphFrame]
  [width=max,
   align=normal]

\starttext

\placeframed
  [ParagraphFrame]
  {\samplefile{weisman}}

\placeframed
  [ParagraphFrame]
  [foregroundstyle={\setupinterlinespace[line=4ex]}]
  {\samplefile{weisman}}

\stoptext
```

[image]